# How to make an android Instant-app with navigation-drawer in base feature?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to make an instant-app with a navigation-drawer placed in the base feature and each item should launch an url intent to  its own feature module.

How can make url intents that launches a feature with the navigation drawer thats placed in the base feature present?

**App**

**Instantapp**

**Base feature**

- navigation drawer

**Feature 1**

- activity or fragment

**Feature 2**

- activity or fragment

Comment: Please can you check this URL for details https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194187/how-to-test-instant-app-with-multiple-features/44200267#44200267